# How to check if any span element in inside div has empty value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below code in my html file

```
<div id="tags" style="border:none">
<span class="tag" id="spantag">{{ stu_skill.skill }}</span>
</div>
```

Values inside the above span will be added dynamically from the server.. there will be maximum of 7 spans (spans[0],spans[1] and so on till spans[6])

How can I check if any of the spans is empty in javascript or Jquery ?

So far, I tried the below but didn't get through

```
var div = document.getElementById("tags");
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");
if (spans[0].innerHTML.length == 0)
{
spans[0].innerHTML=="EMPTY";
}
```

like this, and also

```
if($('spans[0]').text().length == 0){
$(".tag").text("EMPTY");
window.alert("Spans[0] has no value, it is now " + $(".tag").value);
}
```

I'm trying to check if there is empty span, if that is found, I need to just update it with string "EMPTY" or " "

Could you please suggest with the right approach for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voilà, jQuery has [everything you need](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/):

```
$(".tag:empty").text("EMPTY");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/qsrrqaq7/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("#tags tag").each(function(){
    if($(this).text().length === 0) {
         $(this).text("EMPTY");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` with `:empty`

```
$('#div').find('span:empty')
```